# Parameter to set am/pm in clockpicker()

Tags: jquery, clockpicker

I am using below clockpicker() jquery

```
$('#mon_from').clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

This displays 24 hour clock. Can anybody knows the parameter to set am/pm clock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker), there is a `twelvehour` property you can set to achieve what you need. By default it's `false`, you require `true`:

```
$('#mon_from').clockpicker({
  autoclose: true,
  twelvehour: true
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! it worked. Actually i tried to find in the document, but i was in this document: **https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/** and here i did not find this option. Anyway, thanks :-)